# json yield works correctly in log records, but when I print with settext in textview, only one yield appears

Tags: android, json, android-studio, settext

In the log results, all json data is written completely but when I do it with settext technique, only 1 yield is written. I want to print all of my json output to my edittex.
Can you help ? thanks.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40228440/64487408-ed27e500-d242-11e9-9778-f699f5b52cb0.png

```
 String  jsonveri = "{\"bayraklar\":[{\"bayrak_id\":\"1\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"T\\u00fcrkiye\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"turkiye\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"2\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Almanya\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"almanya\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"3\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"\\u0130talya\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"italya\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"4\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Fransa\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"fransa\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"5\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Hollanda\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"hollanda\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"6\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"\\u0130spanya\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"ispanya\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"7\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Slovenya\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"slovenya\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"8\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Slovakya\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"slovakya\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"9\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Estonya\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"estonya\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"10\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Rusya\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"rusya\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"11\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Bulgaristan\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"bulgaristan\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"12\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Romanya\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"romanya\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"13\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Norve\\u00e7\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"norvec\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"14\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Yunanistan\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"yunanistan\"},{\"bayrak_id\":\"15\",\"bayrak_ad\":\"Bosna Hersek\",\"bayrak_resim\":\"bosnahersek\"}],\"success\":1}";
```

I'm only showing the parts of the code that are relevant to this question.

```
try{

    JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject(jsonveri);
    JSONArray liste = jsonO.getJSONArray("bayraklar");

    for (int i=0;i<liste.length();i++){
        JSONObject b = liste.getJSONObject(i);
        int bayrak_id = b.getInt("bayrak_id");
       String bayrak_ad = b.getString("bayrak_ad");
        String bayrak_resim = b.getString("bayrak_resim");

       Log.e("bayrak_id",String.valueOf(bayrak_id));
        Log.e("bayrak_ad",bayrak_ad);
        Log.e("bayrak_resim",bayrak_resim);


        akistwo.setText(bayrak_ad);



    }
```

Comment: You do it in the loop switching text in `EditText` each iteration

Comment: Could not understand? / Could you write sample code?

Comment: `setText()` replaces an old text by a new. Each time u set a new text, so you see the last result only

Comment: I understand thanks but what should I do.

Comment: What should I use instead of settext?

Answer (score 0):

I got help from my udemy teacher to solve this problem.
The solution is very simple.
  textview shows the last post.
so the first post does not appear.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
  edit.setText (sb.append (flag_name));
```

works when I do.
ı love you udemy.